# Laravel: Collection with Multidimensional Association

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Model `User`:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
}
```

Model `Post`:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tag');
}
```

In `Controller`:

```
$user = User::with('posts')->get($id);
```

My collection should contain `user > posts > tags` & I've no idea how can I include `tags` inside `posts` object under `user` collection.

Comment: If you're trying to preload all the tags on the posts, you can change your with to with(['posts','posts.tags']);

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get all user tags through posts?

In this case you can use the hasManyThrough relationship

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    post_id - integer
    title - string
```

Then in User Model

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the tags for the user.
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Tag::class, Post::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can get your user tags with this

```
$user->tags;
```

You can check the full documentation here:

> https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Polymorphic. Here is the official document:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

I'm not quite sure that you can use this query.

```
with('posts.tags');
```